# Filtering multiple select boxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, drop-down-menu

I'm building a website that logs poker game data.

On the 'Add Game' form, I have five drop down menus that map through an array of objects that contain the player data.

What I would like to do is have it so if a player is selected in one drop down, then he is unable to be selected in another, either by becoming unselectable or disappearing completely.

Can anyone think of how to approach this? I've tried searching but can't find anything relevant.

This is my first question here so please go easy on me!

Comment: Maintain a state of players and when the select `onChange` is called remove that player from the state.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.